# jqGrid stuck on Loading... because of invalid XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jqgrid

I have a form with a search box, when triggered the value typed in the input field is sent to a web service, the web service returns XML data to me which I feed into a jqGrid to display a list of results. I got the results to display properly, the problem I have is when no results matching the search criteria are found, when that happens the web service still returns an XML with the usual header but without any dataset. What happens is that the jqGrid displays the "Loading..." box and it stays like that indefinitely and the search feature wont work until the webpage is reloaded.

This is the relevant JS code:

```
$("#buttonSearch").on("click", function() {
    $("#jqSearch").setGridParam({url:"http://website/webservice=filter="+$("#inputSearch").val(),datatype:"xml" }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    $("#divSearchDialog").dialog("open");
});

$("#jqSearch").jqGrid({
    ajaxGridOptions: {
        contentType: 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8',
        timeout: 10000
    },
    datatype: 'local',
    xmlReader: { root:"NewDataSet", row:"Table" , repeatitems:false},
    colNames: ["_ItemGuid", "AssetType", "HostName", "SerialNumber", "Manufacturer", "Model", "Status", "SystemType", "OSName", "OSVersion", "OSType", "Env", "Details"  ],
    colModel: [
        { name: '_ItemGuid', index: '_ItemGuid', hidden:true, xmlmap:"_ItemGuid" },
        { name: 'AssetType', index: 'AssetType', xmlmap:"AssetType", width: 70 },
        { name: 'HostName', index: 'HostName', xmlmap:"HostName", width: 50 },
        { name: 'SerialNumber', index: 'SerialNumber', xmlmap:"SerialNumber", width: 180 },
        { name: 'Manufacturer', index: 'Manufacturer', xmlmap:"Manufacturer", width: 70 },
        { name: 'Model', index: 'Model', xmlmap:"Model", width: 80 },
        { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', xmlmap:"Status", width: 40 },
        { name: 'SystemType', index: 'SystemType', hidden:true, xmlmap:"SystemType" },
        { name: 'OSName', index: 'OSName', hidden:true, xmlmap:"OSName" },
        { name: 'OSVersion', index: 'OSVersion', hidden:true, xmlmap:"OSVersion" },
        { name: 'OSType', index: 'OSType', hidden:true, xmlmap:"OSType" },
        { name: 'Env', index: 'Env', hidden:true, xmlmap:"Env" },
        { name: 'Details', index: 'Details', hidden:true, xmlmap:"Details" },
    ],
    gridView: true,
    loadonce: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    emptyrecords: 'No results found matching your search criteria.',
    width: 960,
    height: 250,
    rowNum: 50,
    loadError: function(xhr,st,err) { 
        if (xhr.status!=200) {
             alert("Error "+xhr.status+" "+xhr.statusText+" loading grid "+this.id);
        }
    }
});
```

This is what the valid XMLs look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<NewDataSet>
    <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="Table">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="_ItemGuid" msdata:DataType="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="AssetType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="HostName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="SerialNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="Manufacturer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="Model" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="SystemType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="OSName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="OSVersion" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="OSType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="Env" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="Details" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <Table>
        <_ItemGuid>912da2ab-d717-678c-a5ad-bb1ece8bcf5f</_ItemGuid> 
        <AssetType>Virtual Machine</AssetType> 
        <HostName>MYSERVER</HostName> 
        <SerialNumber>VMware-42 21 8c 09 00 01 02 03-04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11</SerialNumber> 
        <Manufacturer>VMware, Inc.</Manufacturer> 
        <Model>VMware Virtual Platform</Model> 
        <Status>Active</Status> 
        <SystemType>Win64</SystemType> 
        <OSName>Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard</OSName> 
        <OSVersion>6.1</OSVersion> 
        <OSType>Win</OSType> 
        <Env>PROD</Env> 
        <Details>PROD</Details> 
    </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

If no results are found the XMl looks like this, the Table elements are missing which are the rows Im loooking for in my xmlreader

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<NewDataSet>
    <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="Table">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="_ItemGuid" msdata:DataType="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="AssetType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="HostName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="SerialNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="Manufacturer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="Model" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="SystemType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="OSName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="OSVersion" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="OSType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="Env" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                                <xs:element name="Details" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
</NewDataSet>
```

This is the error I get in the debugger:

```
Unable to get property 'append' of undefined or null reference
```

and this is the piece in jquery.jqGrdid.min.js that triggers it:

```
if(d.p.gridview===!0&&(n=d.p.treeANode>-1?d.p.treeANode:0,d.p.grouping?g||(w.jqGrid("groupingRender",S,d.p.colModel.length,d.p.page,T),S=null):d.p.treeGrid===!0&&n>0?$(d.rows[n]).after(L.join("")):(Y.append(L.join("")),d.grid.cols=d.rows[0].cells)),d.p.subGrid===!0)
```

I tried setting a timeout on my ajaxGridOptions but that didnt seem to do anything, same thing when I added the emptyrecords event. I also tried managing the error with loadError but it doesnt seem to catch it.
I tried a bunch of things with beforeProcessing but I never managed to get it to work.

Has anyone any idea on how to manage this error before it crashes my jqGrid?

Comment: Which jqGrid version you used in your tests?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem using different versions: [latest free jqGrid with data](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/stragz.htm), [latest free jqGrid with empty data](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/stragz0.htm) and [jGrid 4.6 with empty data](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/stragz046.htm). I get never an error which you described. Which jqGrid version you used in your tests? Which web browser you used in your tests?

Comment: Hi Oleg, I typically use IE 11 because that's mostly whats being used internally here but I also tested with Firefox 38.0.1 and in Chrome 43. I get the same result in all of them.

I use jqGrid 5.0.0 which I believe is the latest version.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: **Do you tried the demos**, which I posted you in my previous comment (click on the links in the comment)? The demos uses your XML data and your code and I don't see any error which you describe in your question.

Comment: Yes I did try them, they seem to work fine, I don't get it. The problem only triggers for me when I search for something that returns no results.

Its the only error I get

`if(d.p.gridview===!0&&(n=d.p.treeANode>-1?d.p.treeANode:0,d.p.grouping?g||(w.jqGrid("groupingRender",S,d.p.colModel.length,d.p.page,T),S=null):d.p.treeGrid===!0&&n>0?$(d.rows[n]).after(L.join("")):(Y.append(L.join("")),d.grid.cols=d.rows[0].cells)),d.p.subGrid===!0)`

The Firefox debugger says this: TypeError: Y is undefined

Comment: I did a test similar to yours by having the XML file copied locally on my webserver and it worked. So the issue is most likely with the way the webservice sends me data when no results are found. Again thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but which searching you mean? You wrote that if the searching results are empty then the server returns the second XML (which don't contains the part with `<Table>`). [The second demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/stragz0.htm) and [the third demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/stragz046.htm) load **the same XML data** and you can see no exception. About the code `if(d.p.gridview===!0&&...` which you posted: I asked you **which version of jqGrid you use?**

Comment: There are no differences if you load data from the server or from the file **if the returned XML data really identical**. By the way one should always repeat the tests with non-minimized jqGrid file if one have an exception. One need just replace `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` with `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` (or `jquery.jqgrid.js` in some versions).

Comment: jqGrid 5.0.0
This is the non-minimized error

  } else {
   //$("tbody:first",t).append(rowData.join(''));
   **tablebody**.append(rowData.join(''));
**X Unable to get property 'append' of undefined or null reference**
   ts.grid.cols = ts.rows[0].cells; // update cached first row

Comment: I develop alternative fork of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). You can try it by changing URLs to jqGrid files: see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). If you will don't have more the error then you should report the problem to [Guriddo](http://guriddo.net/). It could be a bug in [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) which you use now.

Comment: Ok, I'll try your version and see how it goes and I will let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's an issue with jqGrid 5.0.0, I reverted back to 4.5.4 and it started working flawlessly.